# Compile error: The constructor MessageConsole(String, ImageDescriptor) refers to the missing type ImageDescriptor

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I was working with the following code to print all console output to the console view. But there is a compile error on `MessageConsole`. I have imported the right package `org.eclipse.ui.console.MessageConsole`, I don't know what went wrong. Does anyone know what's up?

[image]

The compile error is this:

> The constructor MessageConsole(String, ImageDescriptor) refers to the missing type ImageDescriptor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type `ImageDescriptor` seems to be referenced indirectly from `MessageConsole` and cannot be resolved. Most likely you need to add a dependency to JFace (the bundle that provides `ImageDescriptor`) to your bundle.

Either add a `Package-Import` for package `org.eclipse.jface.resource` or add a `Require-Bundle` directive for `org.eclipse.jface` to your manifest.

There may even be a Quick-Fix (<kbd>Ctrl+1</kbd>) to help you solve the problem.